# Libgdx box2d applying dyanamic_body.applyForceToCenter() not working

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

I have created 1 dynamic and 1 static body in box2dworld and i want to make the dynamic body moving in the horizontal direction by making a slope but it is not working at all. This is the code:

```
public class Box2dBodyTest implements ApplicationListener
{
    World world;
    Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    @Override
    public void create() 
    {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false);

        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true); 

        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        createDynamicBody();

        createStaticBody();
    }

    private void createDynamicBody()
    {
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        // We set our body to dynamic, for something like ground which doesn't move we would set it to StaticBody
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        // Set our body's starting position in the world
        bodyDef.position.set(100, 300);

        // Create our body in the world using our body definition
        Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

        // Create a circle shape and set its radius to 6
        CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
        circle.setRadius(6f);

        // Create a fixture definition to apply our shape to
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = circle;
        fixtureDef.density = 0.5f; 
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.6f; // Make it bounce a little bit

        // Create our fixture and attach it to the body
        Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        body.applyForceToCenter(10.0f, 0.0f, true);

        // Remember to dispose of any shapes after you're done with them!
        // BodyDef and FixtureDef don't need disposing, but shapes do.
        circle.dispose();
    }


    private void createStaticBody()
    {
        // Create our body definition
        BodyDef groundBodyDef = new BodyDef();  
        // Set its world position
        groundBodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(0, 10));  

        // Create a body from the defintion and add it to the world
        Body groundBody = world.createBody(groundBodyDef);  

        // Create a polygon shape
        PolygonShape groundBox = new PolygonShape();  
        // Set the polygon shape as a box which is twice the size of our view port and 20 high
        // (setAsBox takes half-width and half-height as arguments)
        groundBox.setAsBox(camera.viewportWidth, 10.0f);
        // Create a fixture from our polygon shape and add it to our ground body  
        groundBody.createFixture(groundBox, 0.0f); 
        // Clean up after ourselves
        groundBox.dispose();
    }


    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();

        world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);

        debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    }
}
```

I have searched a lot and tried my best to solve this problem by going through box2d tutorials etc. but is not getting solved. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use realistic sizes when dealing with Box2d. Box2d assumes the ratio of one pixel per meter which isn't very practical to most programmers. When you define your circle fixture you set the radius to 6.0f, which means that **Box2d creates a circle with a diameter of 12 meters or 39 feet** . That is huge. I suggest taking a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDZMRDb1A_M#t=812). It really helped me when I was struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the ratio of 1 pixel / meter and how to make it realistic and worth use?

Comment: Waiting for your response sir.

Comment: The thing is that when you are applying the force to your circle if it moves for example 1 meter, it only moves one pixel making it hard to see. You have to convert all the Box2d sizes and camera size with the ratio you want. I personally use 8 pixels per meter which isn't necessary but works out for me.

Comment: And again I suggest watching the video, it explains it well with code examples. You can fast forward to around 13:30 if the link doesn't do it for you. I can explain more too if needed.